# How can I convert an encrypted data as string and decrypt the data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I convert an encrypted data as string and decrypt the data in SQL Server 2008?

I have tried the following

Encrypt data:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT([varchar](512), EncryptByPassPhrase('Nessis22',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), '6234')), 2)
```

Result :

```
0x01000000F2AA862E820415737E99B1EDA7D3EF47225DAA898A744B118908BE626EE2510E
```

Decrypt data:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), DecryptByPassPhrase('Nessis22'
, 0x01000000F2AA862E820415737E99B1EDA7D3EF47225DAA898A744B118908BE626EE2510E))
```

Output:

```
(No column name)
6
```

Data got truncated. How can I get complete string?

Comment: You cannot store the result of `EncryptByPassPhrase` as `varchar(512)`. the function is documented to return `varbinary(8000)` and **that** is what you should store the result as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NVARCHAR within your decrypt SELECT:

```
select convert(NVARCHAR(max),DecryptByPassPhrase('Nessis22'
, 0x01000000F2AA862E820415737E99B1EDA7D3EF47225DAA898A744B118908BE626EE2510E))
```